# Ubuntu Gnome: Disable second screen by default

Tags: command-line, gnome, nvidia, screen, ubuntu-gnome

I have an Nvidia GTX 670 with a 22' Samsung Monitor and a 40' Sony HDTV. My problem is every time I log in Ubuntu, I have to manually disable the TV (I use Ubuntu mainly for programming and surfing the internet, so I don't use the TV at all). In Windows I can easily disable my TV and if I want to see a movie, I can enable it with Ctrl + P. Is very annoying to lose my mouse pointer every time I go to the right corner (because it passes to the other screen which I don't use and is usually turned off).

Is there a way to make a bash script to disable it (so I can put it in the startup) and enable/disable it? (so I can use a hotkey every time I want to use the TV).

Thanks in advance!

PS: I'm in Ubuntu Gnome 14.03 LTS

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If the below answers your question, don't forget to click the grey **☑** under the very small number at the left of the answer, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

xrandr will list your existing outputs. Get the id of the tv, then do `xrandr --output $TV --off` to turn if off. Or `xrandr --output $TV --auto` to turn it on. Not sure about toggling, but you might be able to hack something together.

Comment: Good one!  upvoted!  ;-)